# WebSphere - Resource interpreted as Stylesheet / Script but transferred with MIME type text/html

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, websphere, websphere-liberty

This is a very frustrating problem. I have a login page for my web application and the HTML looks like below. As you can see, I'm using the form based auth *(auth-method=FORM)* provided by WebSphere Application Server and hence the form action="j_security_check".

This works locally on my local WAS Liberty Edition Server v8.5 fine with all CSS rendered properly. But when I deploy this to a remote server (IBM WAS v8.0.0.5) and open the app using Chrome/FF/IE8 the follwoing happens,
a. Stylesheet is not applied
b. I see the following error in my Chrome web tools -- Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://example.com:9081/PSSU/login2.html". login2.html:
c. Even if I try to sign in, the broswer display's the bootstrap.css file
b. The other HTML pages render fine with the stlying

I checked the MIME types in the server VirtualHosts and I can see definitions for application/javascript (for .js) and text/css (for .css).

**Am'I missing something here? Any pointers / help would be much appreciated.**

*PS: The behavior is also the same in a Tomcat container*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Sign in ...</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <!-- Le styles -->
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        padding-top: 40px;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
        background-color: #f5f5f5;
      }

      .form-signin {
        max-width: 300px;
        padding: 19px 29px 29px;
        margin: 0 auto 20px;
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
           -moz-border-radius: 5px;
                border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
           -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
                box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
      }
      .form-signin .form-signin-heading,
      .form-signin .checkbox {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
      }
      .form-signin input[type="text"],
      .form-signin input[type="password"] {
        font-size: 16px;
        height: auto;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        padding: 7px 9px;
      }

    </style>
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <form class="form-signin" action="j_security_check" method="post">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
        <input id="j_username" name="j_username" type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Email address">
        <input id="j_password" name="j_password" type="password" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Password">
        <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit">Sign in</button>
      </form>
    </div> <!-- /container -->

    <!-- Le javascript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-alert.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-button.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "The behavior is the same in the Tomcat container" - which behavior, correct rendering of CSS as with the Liberty profile? or the incorrect rendering of the stylesheets seen on WAS 8.0.0.5 ...

Comment: i get the same answer using openshift - any help?

Comment: @user456563 Did you ever solve this? Facing a similar issue.